# Retrieve Values from a sorted and data bound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

I want to set the gActiveRowIndex to the index of the row where it is in the datatable, even if the datagridview is sorted.

What I have works only if the datagridview has not been sorted, I'm looking for a way to set gActiveRowIndex to the index of the row in the datatable corresponding to the row of the datagridview that was clicked.

Data Table:

```
Dim CustomerDataTable = New DataTable("Customer Data")
CustomerDataTable.Columns.Add("Customer Id", GetType(Integer))
CustomerDataTable.PrimaryKey = {CustomerDataTable.Columns("Customer Id")}
CustomerDataTable.Columns.Add("Firm und Customer Name")
CustomerDataTable.Columns.Add("Zip City")
CustomerDataTable.Columns.Add("Street")
```

Form:

```
Dim customerDataTable As DataTable

Sub getAdoRecords(dt As DataTable)
    customerDataTable = dt
    dgv_Search_Results.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_Search_Results_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv_Search_Results.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        gActiveRowIndex = e.RowIndex
        gActiveCustomerId = customerDataTable.Rows(e.RowIndex)(0)
        RaiseEvent SelectedValueChanged(sender, e)
        Close()
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: If the control is indeed DataBound, you ought not be getting the values from the control at all but from the data source.

Comment: But the way the program works is by a user clicking a cell in the datagridview so it can use the row of data clicked, but I can't find a way to know which row in the datatable corresponds to the clicked row in the datagridview when sorted.

Comment: Does the DataGridView contain the primary key of the record?

Comment: Yes, but it is in the data table. I added the data table definition code above.